# eclipse build errors

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I am getting this error in regular interval.

```
'Building workspace' has encountered a problem.

Errors occurred during the build.
    Errors running builder 'JavaScript Validator' on project 'bankinguru'.
    java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I am using

```
Eclipse for PHP Developers

Version: Helios Release
Build id: 20100617-1415
```

under `Ubuntu 10.10` . Is there anyway to solve this problem?

[**EDIT**]: StackTrace of `workspace/.metadata/.log`

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 75 2011-02-26 15:28:28.901
!MESSAGE Errors occurred during the build.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core 4 75 2011-02-26 15:28:28.901
!MESSAGE Errors running builder 'JavaScript Validator' on project 'bankinguru'.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.ConditionalExpression.analyseCode(ConditionalExpression.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.ArrayInitializer.analyseCode(ArrayInitializer.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.analyseCode(LocalDeclaration.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.Block.analyseCode(Block.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.IfStatement.analyseCode(IfStatement.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.analyseCode(MethodDeclaration.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.analyseCode(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.analyseCode(MethodDeclaration.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.analyseCode(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.FunctionExpression.analyseCode(FunctionExpression.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.Expression.analyseCode(Expression.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.analyseCode(MessageSend.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.analyseCode(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:589)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.compile(BatchImageBuilder.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.build(BatchImageBuilder.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.buildAll(JavaBuilder.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace?  Look in the Error Log view.

Comment: @Andrew Eisenberg where can I get the stack trace -- the above message is from a dialog box the pops out.

Comment: Open the error log view:  Window -> Show View -> Error log.  Please include the full stack trace and any messages.

Comment: @Andrew Eisenberg I am using eclipse for `PHP` development and I don't find `Error log` under Show View menu

Comment: I'm not familiar with that flavor of Eclipse, but I guess it's not included with the distribution.  You should be able to find the log file in the workspace/.metadata/.log file instead.  Without a full stack trace or any more information, it is impossible to know what is going on.

Comment: @Andrew Eisenberg found it, here you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is starting to look like a bug in the JavaScript support.  See here:

http://www.myeclipseide.com/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=115100

and here:

http://myeclipseide.com/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=115099

I'd recommend raising a bug report at:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/

You should include this stack trace as well as a way that you can reproduce the exception.

Answer (score 2):

This is occurring because Eclipse is trying to run Javascript Validation on a PHP project.  To stop this error, go to 'properties' under the 'project' menu.  Select the 'builders' option and deselect 'Javascript Validator'.  This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. It's easy to forget. This should be the accepted answer IMO.